# Convert each element of array into separate array in JavaScript (ES6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Convert each element of array into separate array and push into one array.

```
inputArray = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

Required Output

```
outputArray = [['One'],['Two'],['Three']]
```

By using ES6 how to get this output?

Answer (score 3):

You an use [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do that:

```js
const inputArray = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
const result = inputArray.map(x => [x]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean a simple map of each element? That can be done very quickly like so

```
const outputArray = inputArray.map(el => [el]);
```